# How to go through 2 models in a loop in ruby on rails ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using MailKick gem and I am sending emails to users from id 1 to 1000 who have not opted out to get emails.

So I have

```
@users = User.where('id >= 1').where('id <= 1000')
@opt_out_users = Mailkick.opt_outs.where(active: true)

User model has id, email and name as fields.
MailKick model has id, email, user_id and active as fields.
```

Now I can run the code

```
@users.each do |user|

//Code to send emails to each user

end
```

but I am not able to figure out how to filter out those users who have opted out.

Comment: I don't get it. Is opt_outs an association to a seperate model?

Answer (score 4):

As [documentation says](https://github.com/ankane/mailkick#sending-emails), you should add `mailkick_user` to your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mailkick_user
end
```

Then scope `.not_opted_out` will be avaliable for you:

```
User.not_opted_out.where('id <= 1000').each { |user| user.do_smth }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use

```
@users = User.where.not(
  id: Mailkick.opt_outs.where(active: true).pluck(:user_id)
).where("id <= 1000")
```

The clause `.where('id >= 1')` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one command:

```
@users_who_have_not_opted_out = User.where(id: 1..1000)
  .where.not( id: MailKick.op_outs.where(active: true).pluck(:user_id) )
```

The first `where` function gets all ids between 1 and 1000.  The second `where.not` statement returns all ids that are not in the opt_out list.  The `pluck(:user_id)` turns the `MailKick.opt_outs.where(active:true)` association into an array of `user_ids`

You can then run:

```
@users_who_have_not_opted_out do |user|
  # Here you would execute your send email command on user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all user ids who are not opted out like this,

```
@opt_out_users = Mailkick.opt_outs.where(active: true,:user_id=>{'$gte'=>1,'$lte'=>1000}).map(&:user_id);
```

The above statement will return the user ids in an array.
Next you can can search user object using those ids.

```
@user = User.where(:id=>{'$in'=> @opt_out_users});
```

And loop through each user

```
@user.each do |user|
   #code for sending mails
end
```